# What Roles or Privileges are needed for ALTER DATABASE ADD SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm attempting to run the following command as I am trying to get logminer to log my database.  When I run the following command, I get a response of Insufficient Privileges

```
ALTER DATABASE ADD SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA;
```

I have to run it as a specific user, so I need to know what Granted Roles and/or System Privileges are required to run this statement.

Comment: The prereqs, including necessary granted privs, for any sql statement are listed in the explanation of the statement in the [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ALTER-DATABASE.html#GUID-8069872F-E680-4511-ADD8-A4E30AF67986)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a DBA (and stuff like that *are* supposed to be run by DBA), but: privileged user should grant you (as you said that you'll be running it yourself) the `ALTER DATABASE` privilege:

`scott` is just a poor user:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL>
SQL> alter database add supplemental log data;
alter database add supplemental log data
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

A privileged user is `SYS` (if you don't have any other):

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant alter database to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Back to `scott`, re-run the statement:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> alter database add supplemental log data;

Database altered.

SQL>
```

---

That's the *minimum*. You could have also granted the DBA role to `scott`, with the same effect (regarding this very statement, but - DBA is much more powerful):

To illustrate it, revoke the privilege first:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> revoke alter database from scott;

Revoke succeeded.
```

Does it still work? Of course not:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> alter database add supplemental log data;
alter database add supplemental log data
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Grant DBA role:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant dba to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Does it work now? Yes, it does:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> alter database add supplemental log data;

Database altered.

SQL>
```